# R Sweave output error

Tags: r, sweave

I'm using RStudio v0.96.331 with pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian).
I have a R project in the '/home/operacao/Myprojs/projName', which is my working directory.

Now, if i create a folder called 'reports' in '/home/operacao/Myprojs/projName/reports', and inside the sweave file (which is in the reports folder) use the code

```
  setwd('/home/operacao/Myprojs/projName')
```

After loading some packages, i receive the error

```
 Error in driver$finish(drobj) : 
 the output file 'my_report.tex' has disappeared
 Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous>
 Execution halted
```

But the file is in the folder, and the plots i made appear in the .pdf. The text output
does not appear.

Anyone knows why that happens? If i save the Sweave files in my directly in my working directory, everything works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Thou shall never `setwd()` inside a report! `setwd()` should always be kept out of a report, otherwise you will ruin the output structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably RStudio requires you to set the working directory to the location which contains the Sweave file. Why do you need to set your working directory to another directory? You could use `source` to load any R code files which are in `projName`.

Comment: My working directory is the project directory, but i dont want to mess it with the sweave output, thats why i created a 'reports' folder.